Is there an R function to calculate z-value of standardized residuals in chi-square test as in SPSS?
I've been asked to calculate the z-value of standardized residuals in chi-square test, does this make sense? If so, how can it be calculated in R?
Example:
observed <- matrix(c(30, 10, 20, 15), nrow = 2, byrow = TRUE)
chi_sq_test <- chisq.test(observed)


Are the values you're looking for chi_sq_test$stdres?

It is good practice to read the docs carefully--almost always. Look at Value under help("chisq.test").
